# Unable to install ubuntu 64 on virtualbox windows 8 host

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, windows-8-x64

While trying to install ubuntu 13 on windows 8 host, it throws the error "this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686". However, mine is a new dell xps 8700 with haswell i4770 and I verified virtualization is enabled in bios. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to run 64-bit guest operating system on a 32-bit host operating system.  What product you have exactly.  Certain Haswell prodcuts do not have the abiity to do that.

Comment: I thought dell xps8700 was only sold with windows 64bit. @Kiran: when you defined the new VM, did you check "Ubuntu 64bits"?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, You are right, I have not selected that option. Infact, I have not even noticed that option until you pointed out. Trying it out now.

Comment: @Ramhound, it is running windows 8 in 64bit mode..

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, that is infact the reason. Post it as answer and I will accept it.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a new VM, you must check the "Ubuntu 64bits" option  under the Version drop-down menu.